# Eloquent Javascript: The sum of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want a sum function that takes an array of numbers and returns the sum of these numbers.

I wrote the following, but it always returns `undefined`:

```
function sum(array){
    var sumVar;
    for(i = 0; i <= array[array.length]; i++){
        sumVar += array[i];
    }
    return sumVar;
}

console.log(sum([1,2,3]));
// → undefined
```

Could anyone help explain why this is happening? I'm not so much concerned with the solution as I am with what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: an eloquent solution for sum would take advantage of [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While there are multiple areas of your code which seems incorrect (as addressed by @meagar), the reason why you still get `undefined` after changing your loop iteration to stop at `array.length` is because you didn't initialize `sumVar` to 0.

```
function sum (array) {
    var sumVar = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1) {
        sumVar += array[i];
    }
    return sumVar;
}

sum( [1, 2] ); // results in 3
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. Why do I need to initialize sumVar to zero?

Comment: You need to initialize sumVar to 0 because initially it's value is `undefined`. When you try to add numbers to `undefined`, what you'll end up with is the value `NaN`.

Answer (score 0):

Your condition, `i <= array[array.length]`, makes no sense.

You're looping while `i` is less than `array[array.length]`, which is one-past the last element of the array. This will typically be  `undefined`. `i <= undefined` is always false, and obviously isn't what you want.

If you want to iterate over each element of the array, `i` is the *index* and you need to loop from 0 to one less than `array.length`. Your condition should be `i < array.length`.

Comment: When I try this I get Not a Number. Any ideas why?

Comment: Small nitpick: The end condition of the for loop should be `i < array.length` since JavaScript uses zero-based array indexing.

Answer (score 0):

As **[@zzzzBov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/497418)** hinted in a comment, there is a more eloquent solution than the imperative loop, a solution involving some functional techniques:

```
var add = function(a, b) {return a + b;};
var sum = function(nums) {return nums.reduce(add, 0);};
```

In a library like **[Ramda](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/)**, where functions like `reduce` are curried and the list parameter comes last, this would be even easier (although redundant, since Ramda already includes `sum`):

```
var sum = R.reduce(add, 0);
```

Comment: I have just found out about Ramda today! How long has it been around? 2 years? BTW Isn't your R.reduce() missing the array param? It is nice we can now do R.sum([1,2,3,4,5]) without writing your sum function. We can code JS like Python with Ramda.

Comment: Ramda's about 3 years old.  But the first public announcement was in May, 2014.  Not having the array parameter is very much intentional.  If you want to see a long contentious discussion about the reason for it, there's one at https://github.com/ramda/ramda/issues/452.  I don't think of it much like Python.  More like Haskell, LISP, ML, F#, OCaml and other FP languages.

Comment: Oh ok you did it intentionally. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
function sumOfArray(array) {
   return eval(array.join('+')); 
}

console.log(sumOfArray([4,4])); // result 4+4 = 8
```